# How to check Qt is working or not

Tags: qt, qt4

I installed `Qt version 4.8.5` in my ubuntu machine and how can i test a sample program. Can anyone provide me a sample `.pro` file and `.cpp` file ? or the sample of needful files to test Qt ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find many examples from Qt's website:

http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/all-examples.html

QML examples:
http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qdeclarativeexamples.html